# Magento- attach file to shipment email?

Tags: php, magento

How can I attach a pdf file to the shipment-email. This wil be the same static file attached to alle shipment emails (gov. required terms).

I have looked into som of the files like *dev/lib/mail.php* and *app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Email* also tried to look at some of the code of the [Fooman email attachments extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/FOOMAN/extension/1251/fooman-email-attachments) (wich does not provide the functonality i want), but I'm unsure of how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

`Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->getMail()->createAttachment(...);`

`createAttachment(...)` method is in `Zend_Mail` class.

Answer (score 0):

in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php in send method find

```
$mail->setSubject('=?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->getProcessedTemplateSubject($variables)) . '?='); 
$mail->setFrom($this->getSenderEmail(), $this->getSenderName());
```

and replace with

```
if (isset($variables['attachment'])){   
            $attfile = file_get_contents($variables['attachment']); 
            $attfile = fopen($variables['attachment'],'rb');    
            $att = $mail->createAttachment($attfile);   
            //$att->type = 'plain/text';    
            $att->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;  
            $att->filename = $variables['attname']; 
        }   
        $mail->setSubject('=?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->getProcessedTemplateSubject($variables)) . '?=');

        $mail->setFrom($this->getSenderEmail(), $this->getSenderName());
```